# SmartSVN - Unable to create new repository profile

Tags: linux, svn, repository

I have just installed SmartSVN on this fedora system.

The application starts (on running `./smartsvn.sh`) with its usual UI but many things are not working.

**Creating New repository profile**
Trying to create a new repository profile (Repositories-> Repository Profiles-> Add)

```
An Error occurred while processing an SVN command - 
Cannot connect to 'svn+ssh://192.168.0.103': There was a problem while connecting to 192.168.0.103:22
```

**Quick Checkout**
Trying to do Quick Checkout (less configuration)

```
An Error occurred while processing an SVN command -
 Malformed XML.
```

**Some Observations**
When I run the `smartsvn.sh` file like this:-

```
./smartsvn.sh
```

It shows this in the console -

```
Warning: /bin/java does not exist
Could not lock /root/.smartsvn/_lock_
Switched to running instance
```

I was using SmartSVN in another system before this where it was working. There too, it was showing the warning like `Warning: /bin/java does not exist` but this part was not showing:-

`Could not lock /root/.smartsvn/_lock_ Switched to running instance`

I have only JRE installed in both the systems and not JDK. Eclipse IDE which also needs only JRE is running perfectly fine. So, what could be the reason? Any pointers?

**Updates**
I have just confirmed that it is a smart svn issue. Command line svn is working fine on my system. I created a repository and did a successful checkout.

Thanks,
Sandeepan

Comment: My experience with SmartSVN (Windows version) was not good. Try http://naughtysvn.tigris.org/ or kdesvn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to me like a ssh tunneling problem, SmartSVN is trying to open a ssh connection to a remote server in order to create the new directory, this could be caused by

- Incorrect credentials while trying to connect to the remote server
- SmartSVN is unable to find the ssh binary to execute the command

Try ssh-ing into that remote server without SmartSVN (if possible) and see if that works, also checking the log of the remote server will help you diagnose if you actually arrive to connect there (which would eliminate the second cause out of the possible list)

Try it and let me know which one works for you best

Comment: My repository is actually in the same system, not on a remote system. I am using the root user credentials in smartsvn.