# Unable to connect to my own system through SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

My Fedora system is connected to the internet through a proxy server and we have IPs assigned to every system connected via LAN - mine has `192.168.0.103` (by the way, what is this kind of IP called? the technical term? Anybody). I was trying to setup smartsvn and found that SSH was stopped which is why it was not working. You may check my previous question [SmartSVN - Unable to create new repository profile](https://serverfault.com/questions/221485/smartsvn-unable-to-create-new-repository-profile).

`sshd` was stopped on my system. Trying `ssh root@192.168.0.103` was saying `Connection refused`. Then the fllowing things happened - I don't remember the exact sequence in which they happened -

- I did `service sshd start` and then I got password prompt on trying to ssh.
- I entered the correct password of `root` user but it kept denying saying - `Permission denied, please try again.`.
- I probably restarted sshd and it stopped asking for password on doing `ssh root@192.168.0.103` and kept showing `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` instead.

I checked this solution [ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host](https://serverfault.com/questions/78528/ssh-exchange-identification-connection-closed-by-remote-host/78530#78530) and found that -

- my IP was present in `/etc/hosts.deny`  - `sshd: 192.168.0.103`
- There were failed login attempts in `/var/log/secure`.

So I deleted these things from both these files. After that, `ssh root@192.168.0.103` prompted for password again but again the same problem. Entering correct password says -  `Permission denied, please try again.`

In that file it is written

```
> This file describes the names of the
> hosts which are
> #     *not* allowed to use the local INET services, as decided
> #     by the '/usr/sbin/tcpd' server.
```

But that file cannot be viewed in text. Seems like some more setting needs to be corrected where it is set to disallow this IP for SSH connection. What do I need to fix?

I tried ssh connection from other systems connected via LAN. Permission denied to them too. I logged out and logged in after doing those file changes, restarted sshd and confirmed that those two files do not contain any such thing now.

But still not working. What am I missing. Any pointers?

Thanks,
Sandeepan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loging into a system as root is generally considered to be a bad thing. You will probably find that the that sshd is denying root logins. Check /etc/ssh/sshd_config for the line

`PermitRootLogin no`

Changing no to yes and restarting sshd would allow root to log in. This is however a bad idea. You should connect as a normal user and use `sudo` or `su` to perform administrative tasks.

The IP address you have is an address from one of the [private address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) blocks.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips. For those who are interested to know why exactly "Logging into a system as root is generally considered to be a bad thing", check out http://serverfault.com/questions/41841/why-su-to-root-instead-of-logging-in-as-root

Answer (score 2):

Most linux systems will not permit root to connect to ssh. look for the line

PermitRootLogin no

in file /etc/ssh/sshd_config

I'd opt to use a less privileged user if you can.

Comment: +1 for first correct answer. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to connect as normal user with your password. Does that work?
- Check for line that contains "PermitRootLogin" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. This parameter permits/denies user root to log in via ssh. If set to "no", change it to "yes" and restart ssh server. And try to login again.

You do not have to delete lines in /var/log/*. These files contains logs of previous actions, not state informations.

IP addresses 192.168.*.*, 10.*.*.*, 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 are called "private addresses" defined in RFC1918 to be used in private networks.